# SQL convert month and year to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, datetime

I would like to convert monthofservice column into servicedate column.

For instance, if monthofservice column has  199012 so I would like to have servicedate column to show/load data as 1990-12-01  year-mm-date format. I want date to be default as 01 all time. I would also like to have servicedate column to show NULL when monthofservice column is NULL. With below code it shows as '-' when monthofservice is NULL.

I am sure there is better way to code this and also show servicedate as NULL when monthofservice column is NULL. Any help is highly appreciated!

```sql
SELECT monthofservice 

,CASE WHEN monthofservice = '' THEN NULL ELSE CAST (concat(substring(monthofservice,1,4),+ '-', substring (MonthofService,5,2)+'-'+ '01')) AS VARCHAR (10)) AS servicedate

FROM transaction
```

Note: Servicedate column doesn't exist in transaction table so I am using monthofservice column from trasaction to convert into servicedate and then load data into other destination table using SSIS package.If I can pull NULL through select statement then I think other processes should do the work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `monthofservice`?

Comment: Thanks for your response Monthofservice is character string. I am getting error conversion failed when converting date and/or time from char string. Also, I would like it to show servicedate as NULL when MonthofService is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the month of service is a string, you can simply do:

```
select convert(date, concat(monthofservice, '01'))
```

If you have bad values of `monthofservice`, then use `try_convert()` instead.

Oh, that will also work if `monthofservice` is an integer.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66b97cba917c330dee12b38819ebde3f) is a db<>fiddle.

If the year and month were in separate columns, I would recommend `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(yyyy, mm, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Monthofservice is character string. I am getting error conversion failed when converting date and/or time from char string.  Also, I would like it to show servicedate as NULL when MonthofService is NULL

Comment: @codelearner . . . That would suggest that you have some invalid values in the column.

Comment: I mean it worked very well. Thank you much! I posted another question where I need help on different code.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff I would like to now fetch data from month of service which is character (YYYYMM) format  so it has 202012 so would like to pull only 3 to 6 character meaning I would like to have servicedatetext as 2012 (YYMM ) format so it  needs some adjustment as it is showing BLANK when monthofservice has NULL .. I would like to have NULL when it is NULL in the monthofservice.  I am using  CAST(CONCAT(substring(MonthofService,3,2),substring(MonthofService,5,2)) as Varchar (4)) as servicedatetext                            Servicedatetext is varchar and monthofservice is char.

Comment: @codelearner . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question, elaborate on what you want and provide sample data and desired results.